# Unzip Files With Sub-directories To Root Folder

Tags: c#, .net, zip

I need some help.

I just have this code right now. This code is working, but it's not enough.

My code;

```
DirectoryInfo dirFile = new DirectoryInfo(currentDir);
FileInfo[] infoFile = dirFile.GetFiles("*.zip", SearchOption.AllDirectories);

foreach (FileInfo currentFile in infoFile)
{
    using (ZipFile zipFile = ZipFile.Read(currentFile.FullName))
    {
        zipFile.ExtractProgress += new EventHandler<ExtractProgressEventArgs>(unZipFiles_ExtractProgressChanged);
        foreach (ZipEntry currentZip in zipFile)
        { currentZip.Extract(currentFile.DirectoryName, ExtractExistingFileAction.OverwriteSilently); }
    }
    currentCount = increaseCount + 1; increaseCount = currentCount;
    if (downloadType == 1) { bar2SetProgress((ulong)currentCount, (ulong)totalCount); }
    lblFileName.Text = currentFile.Name;
}
```

I want to extract all zip files to Application.StartupPath folder from _ZipFiles folder with all subdirectories.

Here is one example;

I have one zip folder. Name: _ZipFolder

Before the unzip process;

```
Application.StartupPath\_ZipFiles\startProgram.zip
Application.StartupPath\_ZipFiles\updateProgram.zip
Application.StartupPath\_ZipFiles\Pack\testDownload.zip
Application.StartupPath\_ZipFiles\Pack\Version\repo2.zip
Application.StartupPath\_ZipFiles\Pack\Version\newClass.zip
Application.StartupPath\_ZipFiles\Ack\Library\argSetup.zip
Application.StartupPath\_ZipFiles\Ack\learnMachine.zip
Application.StartupPath\_ZipFiles\Code\zipVersion4.zip
```

After the unzip process (I exactly want to this extract);

```
Application.StartupPath\startProgram.exe
Application.StartupPath\updateProgram.exe
Application.StartupPath\Pack\testDownload.exe
Application.StartupPath\Pack\Version\repo2.cs
Application.StartupPath\Pack\Version\newClass.cs
Application.StartupPath\Ack\Library\argSetup.exe
Application.StartupPath\Ack\learnMachine.pdf
Application.StartupPath\Code\zipVersion4.exe
```

All files needs move to Application.StartupPath from _ZipFiles folder with subdirectories.

How to make this? Please help me.

I hope you understand what I want. I'm sorry for my bad English.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the zip folder name from the current file directory name when extracting

Based on current example where you have `_ZipFiles` folder

```
DirectoryInfo dirFile = new DirectoryInfo(currentDir);
FileInfo[] infoFile = dirFile.GetFiles("*.zip", SearchOption.AllDirectories);

var zipFolderName = @"\_ZipFiles";

foreach (FileInfo currentFile in infoFile) {
    using (ZipFile zipFile = ZipFile.Read(currentFile.FullName)) {
        zipFile.ExtractProgress += new EventHandler<ExtractProgressEventArgs>(unZipFiles_ExtractProgressChanged);
        var destination = currentFile.DirectoryName.Replace(zipFolderName, "");
        foreach (ZipEntry currentZip in zipFile) { 
            currentZip.Extract(destination, ExtractExistingFileAction.OverwriteSilently); 
        }
    }
    currentCount = increaseCount + 1; increaseCount = currentCount;
    if (downloadType == 1) { bar2SetProgress((ulong)currentCount, (ulong)totalCount); }
    lblFileName.Text = currentFile.Name;
}
```

Comment: Thank you sir! You saved my life! Really thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

If I understood you correctly, you want to extract all files to Application.StartupPath directory instead in subfolders.

Try to change:

`currentZip.Extract(currentFile.DirectoryName, ExtractExistingFileAction.OverwriteSilently);`

to

`currentZip.Extract(Application.StartupPath, ExtractExistingFileAction.OverwriteSilently);`

If `Application.StartupPath` isn't suitable, then maybe use `AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory`

Comment: Hello, I already tried this method before, but not working. My subfolders does not exist in the Application.StartupPath.